# opt in to something

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Source: [*You Don't Know JS: Up & Going*](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/up%20&%20going/README.md)  by Kyle Simpson (2014)

Example:

> You can **opt in to strict mode** for an individual function, or an entire
>   file, depending on where you put the strict mode pragma.

The strict mode pragma in JavaScript is just a bunch of words, namely *use strict*, that you put in your source code to enforce stricter compliance with the standards for JavaScript so that your programs are not buggy and perform better. That's just some background information for you. But what I'm really not all that sure about here is how to properly understand the expression *opt in to something* as used in this example. And I think it's particularly that preposition *to* between *opt in* and *something* that's really bothering me here. Could you please help me make sense of things?

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/opt+in help?

Comment: You can choose to join in strict mode? Is that a party we're talking about? That's total nonsense.

Comment: Choose to *join*, yes, essentially.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @CookieMonster: Very little of what computer geeks say ever makes any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Opt in** is related to "option", and in this case means you can turn the strict mode option on locally for the function or globally for the whole source file.

Opt in/opt out is a very common term when dealing with software, and it implies that the other side of the option is default, and you have to explicitly say you want in or out (of the hypothetical group of people who have the option on.)

Many people complain about **opt out** adware in installers, where you have to explicitly select that you don't want a piece of adware when you're trying to install the desired software, or else the installer will give you both by default. Another example is that many features to established software are rolled out as **opt in** options, so that potentially unexpected (though possibly improved) behavior must be selected before it can occur.

**Opt** in a more general sense is synonymous with **choose**. You could opt to have your hot dog with mustard, for example. It's generally used for binary choices, yes or no.

Edit: on "opt in to (option)" specifically, some examples:

> Though our email system uses XMail as the default browser client, you can find in your account settings a way to **opt in to having** Google Apps as your webmail client, which also includes integration with Google Docs and Calendar.

The opposite uses "opt out of (option)" instead of to. This is consistent with most containers, you place something into a box, and you take something out of a box.

> Our new terms of service includes an arbitration clause which stipulates that any disputes you may have with us are not under a civil court's jurisdiction, and that we are the final arbiter of all such disputes. If you do not agree to this, you must **opt out of arbitration** in writing, and send it in a letter marked "Arbitration Opt Out" to our legal team in corporate headquarters.

Comment: Thank you, but I already know all that. You did not answer my question per se though. The pattern at hand is "opt in TO something". That's what my question was about. He didn't say "opt in strict mode", he said "opt in To strict mode". See the difference?

Comment: Oh, sorry. That's just a matter of usage, I suppose. "Opt in to (option)" is just how it is. In non-techy lingo, the option is often a gerund, but it is always a noun. I will edit with a couple examples of this specific form.

Comment: Edited with examples for this specific case.

Comment: Can I say "opt in something" to mean that I choose to include something? (I presume it's possible to say it like that since we can say "opt out something" as you pointed out in your explanation) If that's also a legitimate way to phrase it, then what really is the difference between "opt in something" and "opt in to something"? Sorry, that's just something I still don't get.

Comment: "opt in" is an adjective. "opt in to" is a verb.

Comment: I guess that isn't quite right. "Opt in" is an intransitive verb when it doesn't have another preposition. It can't take an object without "to".

Answer (score 1):

The phrasal verb "opt in" means to choose to become part of an activity, arrangement, program, etc.

The preposition "to" is used before something.  Look at the following sentence taken from The Free Dictionary:

New regulations became effective in July requiring consumers to opt in to banks' programs to pay overdrafts on ATM.